# how do I count head in a crowed scene using haar cascade technique?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to do a head count on street scene.
complete face recognition is not necessary.
it is possible to do that with opencv + haar cascade technique >

Answer (score 0):

This is possible; however, the built-in Haar cascades might not be enough to detect heads in all possible orientations (frontal face and face profile are available). But you can always build your own cascade classifiers, so this is not a big issue.

It's also worth noting that the accuracy of the headcount will greatly depending on the lighting of the scene and the quality of images captured.